# Linux Option of SwitchTothread Windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, linux-kernel

Windows provides a function SwitchTothread which gives chance to run/schedule a lower priority thread. Does anyone know the option in Linux?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

That would be [pthread_yield()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_yield.3.html).

The difference being that `SwitchToThread()` returns nonzero if a thread switch occurred and zero otherwise, whereas `pthread_yield()` returns zero on success and nonzero on error (and always succeeds on Linux for now).

Comment: Note that the yield results in Linux are inconsistent from one kernel version to the next, are not recommended for use, and often result in very poor performance because you may not get to run until even the idle/batch priority threads of all other processes in the entire system have run.

Comment: @Zan then what would be the option for it?

Comment: @CrazyC: Use a condition, mutex or semaphore instead of yielding to other threads at random.

Comment: SwitchToThread is mainly used for priority inversion. And pthread_yield do similar thing. So using synchronization object could not solve out purpose.

Comment: The results of `yield()` vary from kernel to kernel but that's only because the entire nature of the thread scheduling varies.  If your app is dependent on a specific type of thread scheduling paradigm then it's going to have issues across Linux kernels regardless if you're using yield or not.  Furthermore, the bigger affector of both `yield()` and `SwitchToThread()` behavior is the # of cores on the host system.  Typically on quad-core systems yielding the current thread does nothing, or may even reduce performance compared to letting the OS scheduler make its own decisions.

Comment: @CrazyC: If the OS knows what it is doing, when a high priority process blocks on a lock by a low priority process, the low priority process gets to steal the high priority and its timeslice until the lock is released. This is another reason not to roll your own user-space locking code.